# C++ setlocale for any region

Tags: c++, setlocale

I've written a little program for testing purposes because when using cout, the German letters ü ö ä ß were not displayed as they should but rather rubbish was given out on the console. However, using these lines

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "German");
    cout << "üüü ööö äää ßßß" << '\n';
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

have solved this problem, at least as far as the German letters go. When I tried the same for Russian, i. e.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUSSIAN");
    cout << "Кирилица" << '\n';
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

this doesn't work anymore. What is going wrong here? Am I missing something about the setlocale function? My goal is to adapt the respective program to the writing system that is used, for example Cyrillic like aboe or Chinese or whatever.

Comment: I think your second parameter to `setlocale` is incorrect.  For example "German" should be "de_DE".  Possible with an additional encoding eg "de_DE.UTF-8"  see: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/setlocale

Comment: @RichardCritten This is platform-dependent.

Comment: @n.m.  Thanks, so we need the platform added to the question.

Comment: Never ever use non-ASCII characters in source code. This is not portable and you do not control what encoding is being used. Move data to a file where data belongs. Then consider supporting all languages at the same time, rather than one at a time. It's bloody 2017 outside, and your program should be able to say *Hände hoch, товарищ* without any problem.

Comment: I'm working under windows.

n.m: That would be even finer, but honestly I didn't know that this is even possible. I've been struggling with Unicode characters for quite some time now, that's why I asked the question here.

Comment: Look at your browser. Does it show you *Hände hoch, товарищ*? Then yes, it's possible. But not in the way you are trying to do it. Let's start with a simple fact: you cannot sensibly use non-ASCII characters in a `char` literal with the Microsoft compiler.

Comment: Ok, so what should I do to handle any sign right? There are cases where I need to do something with these characters in the program first, not only put them out in the console.

Comment: (Continuing) This worked for German accidentally, it will not work for non-Latin scripts. So you have options: (1) switch to gcc (cygwin/mingw? I have cygwin and it works with Unicode out of the box) (2) switch to wide-characters throughout your code (wchar_t, L"literal", wstring, wcout etc) and UTF-16, (3) use a third-party library that supports UTF-8 (Microsoft compiler/standard library is notoriously bad at supporting UTF-8).

Comment: (continuing) "Am I missing something about the setlocale function?" Yes: the fact that Microsoft compilers don't use it for selecting text encoding, which is the only thing you are interested in right now. There is no standard way to select text encoding. You are probably trying to use UTF-8, because UTF-8 is the default most of the world works with, but In Microsoft universe, there is no way to use UTF-8 for console I/O.

Comment: I've already tried wcout and wstring and L, but it didnt work. To this day, I don't understand why it doesn't work (I teach C++ myself and have only begun last October). I've tried wstring a = L"Кирилица"; and in another line wcout << a << '\n'; however, the output wasn't Кирилица. Actually, in this specific case, nothing at all was put out, in another case with some Chinese, only questions marks were put out. Is this supposed to work in Microsoft? I'm working with Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: You need to jump through several hoops in order to enable Unicode I/O in Windows console. Getting your C++ program right is only one of them. It is doable with wcout and wstring and L. First you need to make sure your console is using true type fonts. Getting correct characters out is useless if you can't see them! If you can type cyrillic characters and see what you are typing, you are halfway there. Now go back to that wcout and wstring and L program. Open it, then save it as **UTF-8 with BOM**. (important). Compile it with VC++. Does it work?

Answer (score 1):

FOR GERMAN  -> std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "de_DE");
FOR RUSSIAN -> std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");